# How to implement custom methods for CrudRepository?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-batch, spring-data-jpa

I'd like to create a `RepositoryItemWriter` and supply a custom `CrudRepository` method.

Problem: `CrudRepository` is an interface, and if I implement it in a `public class`, then I'd have to explicit implement all of the methods.

So, how can I create a custom method implementation within a `CrudRepository`?

```
    @Autowired
    private MyEntityRepository repository;

    @Override
    public ItemWriter<PricingCache> temWriter() {
        RepositoryItemWriter<MyEntity> writer = new RepositoryItemWriter<>();
        writer.setRepository(repository); //expects a CrudRepository
        writer.setMethodName("save"); //how to change this to a custom method? eg firstValidatenThenSave()
        return writer;
    }

public interface MyEntityRepository extends CrudRepository<MyEntity, Long> {
}
```

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations

Answer (score 2):

You have several options for customizing Spring Data methods and repositories.

If you are using Java8, you could provide a "default" method on your interface.

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryRestResource;

import java.util.UUID;

@RepositoryRestResource(path = "sample", collectionResourceRel = "sample")
public interface SampleRepository extends CrudRepository<Sample, Long> {

    @Override
    default Sample save(Sample sample) {

        System.out.println("DEFAULT SAVE CALLED!!");
        sample = new Sample();
        sample.setId(System.currentTimeMillis());
        sample.setWhatever("stuff");
        return sample;
    }

    @Override
    default Sample findOne(Long id){

        System.out.println("DEFAULT FIND CALLED!!");

        Sample sample = new Sample();
        sample.setId(id);
        sample.setWhatever(UUID.randomUUID().toString());

        return sample;
    }
}
```

If you are using Spring Data Rest, then you could create your own RepositoryRestController with a request mapping that "overrides" or replaces the path you want to customize.

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryRestController;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@RepositoryRestController
public class SampleController {

    @RequestMapping(path = "/sample", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public void delete(Long deleteMe){

        System.out.println("RepositoryRestController CALLED for "+deleteMe);
    }
}
```

You can create some custom query methods using the @Query annotation.

```
@Override
@Query(value = "SELECT DISTINCT count(*) FROM SAMPLE_DISTINCT")
long count();
```

Spring Data Rest also has a naming convention you could use to create custom search/findby methods. For example, if my person object has a firstName and a lastName, I could create the following method interfaces and Spring Boot will implement them for me.

```
List<Person> findByFirstName(String firstName);
List<Person> findByFirstNameStartsWith(String firstName);
List<Person> findByFirstNameEndsWith(String firstName);
List<Person> findByFirstNameContains(String firstName);

List<Person> findByLastName(String lastName);
List<Person> findByLastNameStartsWith(String lastName);
List<Person> findByLastNameEndsWith(String lastName);
List<Person> findByLastNameContains(String lastName);

List<Person> findByFirstNameAndLastName(String firstName, String lastName);
List<Person> findByFirstNameContainsAndLastNameContains(String firstName, String lastName);
//etc...
```

This should work on repository interfaces declared for data-rest and data-mongodb as well.